# Puppet::Environments::EnvironmentNotFound when folder exists

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

I have file structures for 2 environments on my puppet master server. Running `ls /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/` on my master server returns two folders `beta` and `production`.

Yet when I go on my agent and run `puppet apply -t --environment beta` I get the error:

```
/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/environments.rb:38:in `get!':
Could not find a directory environment named 'beta' anywhere in the path: /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments.
Does the directory exist? (Puppet::Environments::EnvironmentNotFound)
```

On the master server I can successfully apply the beta manifest with `puppet apply /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/beta/manifests/site.pp`.

I'm trying to figure out why Puppet isn't detecting the folder. How can I go about debugging this?

I also tried `puppet agent -t --environment beta`, as suggested by @gd_, which returns:

> Notice: Local environment: 'beta' doesn't match server specified node
>   environment 'production', switching agent to 'production'.

**`/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf` (on agent) is as follows:**

```
# This file can be used to override the default puppet settings.
# See the following links for more details on what settings are available:
# - https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/config_important_settings.html
# - https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/config_about_settings.html
# - https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/config_file_main.html
# - https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/configuration.html
```

*Using open source version.*

Comment: @gf_ I will find the information you requested and update my question.

Comment: Well, you wrote that you're using `puppet apply -t --environment beta`, which is not a valid call. Try with `puppet agent ... `.

Comment: @gf_ sorry I misread. I've updated my question after trying your suggested solution.

Comment: It's not considered good practice to edit questions with new errors which are coming up. I would suggest to mark this question as solved, and create a new one. Anyway: Which version is this? Also: Is this open source or puppet enterprise? Searching for the error gives quite some hints what could be wrong.

Comment: @gf_ why would I mark as solved when I still get the same error but worked differently? My original problem is that puppet master isn't seeing the environments from my environments folder and I'm still having that problem.

Comment: Show the config of your puppet master.

Comment: Just as a final hint: If both, the master and the agent, via their respective config or via the CLI, request a specific environment, the master wins. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `puppet agent ...`, instead of `puppet apply ...`. The params you're using apply to the former, not the later.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I still get a similar, but slightly different error.

Comment: The error is not really similar. It means that the server is overriding the environment and or providing the environment on the CLI is disabled. Searching for the error gives quite some hints.

Comment: you are 100% right. Sorry about that I should have read more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

another option is that in the **/etc/hosts** of the agent - the name of the server is not as appears in the result of the command `hostname`
this can cause confusion when the agent communicate with the puppet server